# cant install gnome on parrot os because of unmet dependency

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, gnome, parrot-os

I have been trying to install `parrot-desktop-gnome` on parrot os.

running `sudo apt install parrot-desktop-gnome` gives me this output:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EbdK.png)

I tried update and upgrade commands

this is my `source.list`:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaVTD.png)

Comment: My recollection is that you need Wayland installed to install Gnome.  Did you do that?

Comment: @John no I did not

Comment: Try this guide:    https://parrotsec.org/docs/configuration/desktop-enviroments/

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: You are out of luck then.  Use Parrot's desktop interface.  Or otherwise use Ubuntu which has been honed for Gnome.

Comment: @John Yes '_' I was using Kali for penetration testing. I thought about moving to Parrot, but I am unlucky. I am thinking about using Arch Linux now. Thank you appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get Gnome on ParrotOS, installing using the Architect version. But be aware that the installer for that version has a known bug that may prevent you from installing the additional software. In that case, use [this workaround](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/w8edlr/cant_install_arm64_parrot_os_in_parallels_desktop/), so install an empty cli version by clicking "Go back" after the base OS is installed and skipping the "select and install software" step. Afterwards you can install whatever DE you want (parrot-desktop-gnome still gave me the same error, but just `sudo apt install gnome` worked fine.

You can then install the rest of the Parrot App Suite with `tasksel`